# iterating over HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript, arrays, htmlcollection

I have an HTMLCollection containing all HTML nodes that use the script tag. I collect them by `const scriptNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('script');`.

If I log the whole collection in Chrome dev tools, its length is `10`. If I unfold the collection and see its properties, I can see more than 10. I can even see a property called `length`, which is 12. This means that there are 2 properties not accessible.

I try to access to `scriptNodes[10], scriptNodes[11]` and they are undefined. Even the API `HTMLCollection.nodeItem(index)` returns undefined, which they are not, I can see the content of those 'extra' properties.

I have tried `for..of, for..in` and those are not logged.

How am I supposed to access those extra/undefined properties? Is that something related to Enumerability?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

A number of browser extensions can add script tags to your page. I am guessing that is why those extra script tags are showing up. Possibly you are accessing the script tags at a point in time before the extra ones are loaded. If you place your code inside a setTimeout, you would likely get all of the script nodes. Try it and let us know if that is it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var scriptNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
        console.log('scriptNodes', scriptNodes);
    }, 2000); // or an even longer delay if you like
});
```

Comment: I can assure that no browser extension has added any script in my html.
console.log('scriptNodes', scriptNodes); is logging all scripts, but in a for loop, it does not access those extra properties.